# Python ValueError: View function did not return a response

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, valueerror

I'm having trouble understanding the ValueError I'm getting when running my Python code for my @app.route ("/buy"). Could someone explain what a **ValueError: View function did not return a response** is and how you can avoid this? Also how you'd be able to understand where your problem occurs with the error message that is given. Much appreciation!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1994, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1615, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1630, in finalize_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1725, in make_response
    raise ValueError('View function did not return a response')
ValueError: View function did not return a response
```

("/buy"):

```
@app.route("/buy", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def buy():
"""Buy shares of stock."""
if request.method == "POST":
    #get symbol from user
    symbl = request.form.get("symbol")
    if not symbl:
        return apology ("Please insert a symbol")

    while True:
        #number of shares to buy
        num = request.form.get("number")

        try:
            number = float (num)
        except ValueError: 
            return apology ("Please insert valid number of stocks you'd like 
            enter code hereto buy")
            continue
        else:
            break
        if number is None or number == '' or number < 1:
            return apology ("Please insert valid number of stocks you'd like 
            to buy")

        #lookup and save dict in quoted
        quoted = lookup(symbl)
        #if symbl is invalid return apology
        if not quoted:
            return apology ("Not a valid stock")
        else:
            #quotedprice saves price of share
            quotedprice=quoted["price"]
            #price of a single share * the number of shares required to buy
            prc=float(qtd)*number
            #remember session id
            ide = session["user_id"]

            csh=db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :ide", ide=ide)
            #continue if user has enough
            if prc <= csh[0]["cash"]:
                db.execute("INSERT INTO portfolio (id, symbol, price, shares, 
                action, dtime) VALUES (:ide, :symbol, :price, :shares, 'Buy', 
                DateTime('now'))", ide=ide, symbol = symbl, price = prc, 
                shares = number)
                db.execute("UPDATE users SET cash = :cash WHERE id = :ide", 
                cash = csh[0]["cash"] - prc, ide = ide)
                return redirect(url_for("index"))
            else: 
                return apology ("Not enough cash to purchase stocks")
else:
    return render_template("buy.html")
```

buy.html:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Please enter the Symbol to buy the stock.
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    <form action="{{ url_for('buy') }}" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="symbol" placeholder="Stock Symbol" type="text"/>
            </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="number" placeholder="Amount of Stock" type="text"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ValueError: View function did not return a response` means that you are not returning anything at the url path `"/buy"`.

At one point of your code:

```
else:
    break
```

you break from your loop, and the function returns nothing. I would replace `break` with `return render_template("buy.html")` or any other response (like `return "Error"` or `abort(500)` which displays an Internal Server Error). Hope this is helpful for you.